# Runlevel pattern for systemd

Tags: systemd, runlevel

Suppose I have two different "runlevels" setup via "targets" in `systemd` - `before.target` (a minimum bootstrap set of services enabled) and `after.target` (run everything).

Right now I do this when I want to switch from "before" to "after":

```
# Set default to after.target. 
/usr/bin/systemctl set-default after.target 1>/dev/null

# Before reboot make sure essential services are enabled
/usr/bin/systemctl enable foo bar baz buz 1>/dev/null

# Reboot
reboot
```

How can I get `foo.service`, `bar.service`, `baz.service`, and `buz.service` added to `after.target` when they are installed?

If I want to configure `boz` to run when `after.target` is enabled, is there any way to do that without modifying the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/after.target` file?

In older systems with chkconfig I would just enable the bootstrap services on say, runlevel 4, and then enable all other services on runlevel 3 but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that here and would prefer not to have to hardcode in `Wanted-By: after.target` in all my service files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is suggested in the systemctl man page:

```
systemctl add-wants after.target foo.service
```

The man page states:

```
       add-wants TARGET UNIT..., add-requires TARGET UNIT...
           Adds "Wants=" or "Requires=" dependencies, respectively, to the
           specified TARGET for one or more units.

           This command honors --system, --user, --runtime and --global in a
           way similar to enable.
```